# Solving $\frac12 (3y+2)-\frac58=\frac34y$ for $y$ using LCD method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am solving $$\frac12 (3y+2)-\frac58=\frac34y$$ for $y$ using LCD method.

Can't figure out what I did wrong! The answer in the back of the book is $-1/2$.

PS: In the first line that is a $1/2$ in front of the $(3y+2)$

[image: http://imgur.com/snY4uIA]

Comment: What is $8[\frac{1}{2}(3y+2)-\frac{5}{8}]$? (i.e. try again)

Comment: You incorrectly distributed the $8$ over a product. You can't do that. It's not generally true that $a(bc)$ is $(ab)(ac)$. Instead, you should just associate the $8$ with one or the other factor. For example, you can write $a(bc)$ as either $(ab)c$ or $b(ac)$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that $\frac{1}{2}(3y + 2)$ is a single term. So when you expand the $8$, you only need to multiply it with the $\frac{1}{2}$ (and not the $(3y + 2)$). Continuing from here, we find that:
\begin{align*}
4(3y + 2) - 5 &= 6y \\
(12y + 8) - 5 &= 6y \\
6y &= -3 \\
y &= -1/2 
\end{align*}